# Possible to populate two levels?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Say I have collections/documents like below:

question collection:

```
{
   _id: ObjectId("0000"),
   title: "test question",
   survey: ObjectId("1234") //abbreviated for question assume this is a legit object id
}
```

---

survey collection:

```
{
   _id: ObjectId("1234"),
   title: "survey title!",
   user: ObjectId("5678")
}
```

---

user collection:

```
{
   _id: ObjectId("5678"),
   Name: "Abe"
}
```

Is there a way for me to call something like:

```
questions.findOne({_id: "0000"}).populate("survey.user")
```

to get the user information along with the question?  I understand that I can populate immediate parents of `question`, but I'm curious if it can be done for grandparents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it in two steps; first populating `survey`, and then populating `survey.user` using a separate call to [`Model.populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate):

```
questions.findOne({_id: '0000'})
    .populate('survey')
    .exec(function(err, question) {
        questions.populate(
            question,
            { path: 'survey.user', model: 'User'},
            function(err, question) {...});
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the best is to nest in the top populate and make it as a object

```js
 Court.
  findOne({ name: 'Val' }).
  populate({
    path: 'events',
    populate: { path: 'authorId' }
  });
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate